# How to install PyCPX (a python wrapper for the IBM CPlex) with Miniconda python on windows 7

Tags: python-2.7, pip, environment-variables, cplex

I'm trying to install PyCPX, a python wrapper for the IBM CPlex optimization suite on windows 7.

[PyCPX](http://www.stat.washington.edu/~hoytak/code/pycpx/)

I am using the python that comes with Miniconda and I've removed the `/usr/bin/python` from my machine to ensure that I'm using the correct one.

When I run `easy_install pycpx` I get the following error.

```
Exception: CPLEX concert include directory not found: please set environment variable CPLEX_PATH to point to the base of the
CPlex/Concert installation. Attempting to find files: ilconcert/iloexpression.h, ilconcert/iloalg.h, ilconcert/iloenv.h, ilconcert/ilosolution.h.
```

I've found this error on another forums listed here

1. [How to get PyCPX installed](http://qiita.com/jellied_unagi/items/e9ce358d2ab44f9e20b9)

This forum has the same error as I but they are using `pip` to install `PyCPX` whereas I am using `easy_install pycpx` as suggested by PyCPX website.

I have set the CPLEX_PATH to point at `C:\Program Files\ibm\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community1263` but it still doesn't pick it up.

I'm am now trying to use `pip` to install it as suggested by the above forum.

The forum suggests using the following:

`pip install --global-option='build_ext' --global-option=-I[the path where you downloaded CPLEX]/CPLEX_Studio1261/cplex/include pycpx`

I'm not familiar with pip, I tried this on my machine but it down't work

`pip install --global-option='build_ext' --global-option=-I[C:\Program Files\ibm\ILOG]/CPLEX_Studio1263/cplex/include pycpx`

Would anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: Try getting rid of the square brackets in your `pip install` command and use quotes around the whole thing.  For example, `pip install --global-option='build_ext' --global-option="-IC:/Program Files/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1263/cplex/include" pycpx`.  Of course, you have "CPLEX_Studio_Community1263" above, and "CPLEX_Studio1263" below ... so, make sure you use the path that actually exists on your machine.